# How to use std::for_each over std::array<> and apply lambda function on each element?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I want to combine these three features together:

- std::for_each
- std::array
- lambda function

into one example using C++11.

```
std::for_each(arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int), [&](int x) { std::cout<<x<<" ";});
```

How to convert that code to operate over `std::array` ?

Comment: Why a `for_each` and a lambda when you can do it better with a range for?

Comment: `std::for_each(begin(arr), end(arr), [](int x) { std::cout<<x<<" ";})`

Comment: `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int)` always gives me the chills. @Oliv pointed to the proper portable way for arrays, std::arrays, containers...

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Some day, the `ExecutionPolicy` parameter comes into play I guess :)

Comment: Very good point indeed :)

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I'm just practicing C++11. It's not a production code. I know that the range for and avoiding lambda will be more readable.

Comment: How about `std::transform`? This is exactly what it's for. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform (Note that the order in which elements are processed is not guaranteed.)

Answer (score 5):

You want  [array::begin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/begin/) and  [array::end](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/end/) of the array, for the two first parameters of [`for_each()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/), which will mark the start and end of the array.

Then the third parameter is a function, in your case a lambda function, like this:

```
std::for_each(myarray.begin(), myarray.end(), [](int x) { std::cout << x <<" "; });
```

---

PS: For a more generic approach, you could use [`std::begin()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/begin/) and [`std::end()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/end/), so that if the container changes (from `std::array` to `std::vector` for example), you can keep this code unchanged.

Comment: @NathanOliver It's 4 characters more and there are no templates involved, so using the more generic version of `begin` and `end` is really not needed

Comment: NathanOliver included it as post note, thanks! @Rakete1111 I agree.

Comment: @gsamaras I'm confused by 'you can keep this code unchanged' remark. Are you saying that std::vector, for example, lacks the begin() and end() members ?? Surely not. So how do the non-member versions improve portability from std:array to std::vector?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite popular on the internet. I grabbed from [std::array in action](http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/std-array-dynamic-memory-no-thanks)

Given:

```
std::array<int, 8> arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
```

Or even:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
```

Use of `for_each` and `lambda`:

```
std::for_each(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), [](int v){std::cout << v << " ";});
```

or even:

```
// calculate the sum of the array by using a global variable
int sum = 0;
std::for_each(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), [&sum](int v) { sum += v; });
std::cout << "sum of array{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}: " << sum << std::endl;
```

**Updated**

Using `std::begin()` and `std::end()` instead of `.begin()` and `.end()` as suggested by @NathanOliver.